# How to add unique constraint to an existing foreignId column in laravel?

Tags: laravel, migration, unique

I have an existing table in database with data and I want to add unique constraints to the customer_id column in it.

I tried doing `$table->foreignId('customer_id)->unique()->change()`. But it doesn't seem to work. The same works for any non foreign fields like string and int.

Error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'customer_id' (SQL: alter table `partner_preferences` add `customer_id` bigint unsigned not
```

null)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`foreignId()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-foreignId) essentially creates a new column which in your case already exists.

> The `foreignId` method is an alias of the `unsignedBigInteger` method:

[laravel - difference between foreignId() and unsignedBigInteger()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61002912/laravel-difference-between-foreignid-and-unsignedbiginteger)

Try this please:

[Unique constraint](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#creating-indexes)

```php
    public function up()
    {
        // Change the 'table name' according to your needs.
        Schema::table("employees", function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->unique('customer_id');
        });
    }
```

**WARNING:** Make sure the column(s) that you're applying this constraint to is actually *unique*. (**Must** have unique data.)

Otherwise, an error (`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'XXXX_customer_id_unique'`) will be thrown.

Comment: So by default `foreignId` is not `unique` correct?

Comment: Is there any way to make the column unique when non-unique data is already present in the column? Or the only way is the truncate the table first?

Comment: @Saurabh , You can't have duplicates if you create a unique key. It's not possible even with raw SQL queries (`ALTER TABLE table_name ADD UNIQUE unique_constraint_name (unique_columns)`).  Your best bet would be to first remove the duplicates if you're working with production data. For test data, it is okay to truncate the table first.

Comment: @Saurabh A safe way is to duplicate the column. i.e. rename the old one, create a new one with the original's name, make it unique AND nullable, then write a method to copy the data from the old column into the new column. But your method should only keep the first occurrence of a value, and leave the subsequent occurrences as NULL.